# Django javascript cannot be loaded after doing changes

Tags: javascript, django, static

Guys

Currently, I am doing the Django website development
Django version: 1.11.13

I added static folder in each app.
and DEBUG = True in the settings.py

the static files(javascript and css) can be found, but when I changed/added content in css, it can be reloaded. but the javascript cannot.

what I did are:

```
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/dashboard.js' %}?{% cache_bust %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

cache_bust is templatetags which will add uuid at the end of js link. 
**it does not work for the reloading of javascript in the browser.**

I chose the **all time** to clear the cache in the browser. **it does not work for the reloading of javascript in the browser.**

python manage.py collectstatic, **it still does not work**

only I can do was create another js file, this change can be detected by the browser.

I do not think it makes sense. do you have this same issue, and how to figure it out? any suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: I had the similar problem with Pycharm IDE with CSS files. For me helped to rename the file each time it is edited. But also don't know what is the issue here.

Comment: I would start debugging by looking at the *client-side browser* debugging console.  Look at the HTML output that the application is sending, then "clear browser caches" and pore through the list of HTTP exchanges that the browser went through in loading the page.

Comment: @Chiefir:  I am using PyCharm as well. I have switched to using console and edit at Eclipse, the issue does not change.
I think probably you need to add cache bust at the end of each static files. let's see it. I researched for a while, it works for some people, but it did not work for me.
https://github.com/mgrp/django-cachekiller

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes, this was what I did. We can see the static files which sent from django server, and the javascript file does not changed, the django side already updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause.
In the Django, the user defined files of javascritpt, css should under static folder, not static/assets in each app.

Comment: can you explain more what do u mean? I can't have nested `css` and `js` folders in `static` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Safari to open this project, the changed file still could not be loaded. this is kind of weird.
What I thought at the earlier of the day was the browser issue, but right now, it definitely comes from Django. 
I do not know it related to the configuration or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this recipe how to refresh the css and js files, however it still does not work for me. But I think I am missing with git or BASE_DIR something, cuz it shows the time of last commit, not the time of last local change...

If you don't want to refresh the browser cache each time you change your CSS and JavaScript files, or while styling images, you need to set STATIC_URL dynamically with a varying path component. With the dynamically changing URL, whenever the code is updated, the visitor's browser will force loading of all-new uncached static files. In this recipe, we will set a dynamic path for STATIC_URL when you use the Git version control system.
*Getting ready*
Make sure that your project is under the Git version control and you have BASE_DIR deined in your settings

*How to do it…*
The procedure to put the Git timestamp in the STATIC_URL setting consists of the following two steps:
1.  Add the following content to the `misc.py` file placed in `utils/`:
`utils/misc.py`

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

def get_git_changeset(absolute_path):
    repo_dir = absolute_path
    git_show = subprocess.Popen(
        'git show --pretty=format:%ct --quiet HEAD',
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True, cwd=repo_dir, universal_newlines=True,
    )
    timestamp = git_show.communicate()[0].partition('\n')[0]
    try:
        timestamp = \
            datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
    except ValueError:
        return ""
    changeset = timestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return changeset
```

2. Then, import the newly created get_git_changeset() function in the settings and use it for the STATIC_URL path, as follows:settings.py

`from utils.misc import get_git_changeset
 STATIC_URL = "/static/%s/" % get_git_changeset(BASE_DIR)`

*How it works…*
The `get_git_changeset()` function takes the absolute_path directory as a parameter and calls the git show shell command with the parameters to show the Unix timestamp of the HEAD revision in the directory. As stated in the previous recipe, we pass BASE_DIR to the function as we are sure that it is under version control. The timestamp is parsed; converted to a string consisting of year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds; returned; and included in 
the definition of STATIC_URL.
*(c) Aidas Bendoraitis - Web Development with Django Cookbook, 2nd edition, pg 21. - 2016.* 
**UPDATE**
 And finally I have found a working code after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50551892/8495108) question.

```
import os
def get_file_changeset(absolute_path):
    timestamp = max(map(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x[0]), os.walk(os.path.join(absolute_path, 'static_polo'))))
    try:
        timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
    except ValueError:
        return ""
    changeset = timestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return changeset
```

Add this to you `STATIC_URL` as it is described above and reload dev server each time you edit your static files.

Answer (score 0):

@Chiefir

I had created cache_bust function in tempatetags.

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='cache_bust')
def cache_bust():

    if settings.DEBUG:
        version = uuid.uuid1()
    else:
        version = os.environ.get('PROJECT_VERSION')
        if version is None:
            version = '1'

    return '__v__={version}'.format(version=version)
```

and the url links like below:

```
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/dashboard.js' %}?{% cache_bust %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it still did not work, until I realised the user defined js and css should not stay under the static/assets, since Django won't research any changes under this folder.

I moved the user-defined javascript and css out of assets, and just under the static folder, it works fine.

eg:

static/assets/js/user-defined.js move to static/js/user-defiend.js.

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. My CSS and js files were not working after doing some changes.
So, the thing which worked for me was Changing The Name of the File (CSS or Js which is not working) and change the name of the file inside the address where you are calling that file. It will work.