# How to check the time of last edit in GIT?

Tags: python, git

I have found this code in a book. As it is told there - it might give some specific timestamp each time the code is updated. But as I noticed it just gives a time of *last commit*. Is there a way to get a current time of each code update without comiting it?

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime


def get_git_changeset(absolute_path):
    repo_dir = absolute_path
    git_show = subprocess.Popen(
        'git show --pretty=format:%ct --quiet HEAD',
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True, cwd=repo_dir, universal_newlines=True,
    )
    timestamp = git_show.communicate()[0].partition('\n')[0]
    try:
        timestamp = \
            datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
    except ValueError:
        return ""
    changeset = timestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return changeset
```

**UPDATE:** For those who somehow lands in this page - working code is replace first 3 lines with this:

```
timestamp = max(map(lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x[0]), os.walk(absolute_path)))
```

Comment: You can look at the `mtime` (modified time) of files in a directory to see if it's changed.

Comment: `git` cares only about commits, not about edits

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that my suggestion has nothing to do with git. You'd just be looking at the time files in a directory were last modified. My guess would be a `dir`/`ls` command (whether you're on windows or linux) with a bit of output processing with `sed`.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch but we can see the uncommited `diff` with git? I think the time is something similar?

Comment: @Chiefir git does check for differences (that's what determines what shows up in `git diff`), but it doesn't care about what time those changes were made (it doesn't keep track of it).

Comment: @RThomP thank you for advice of `mtime` - that worked for me. If you want u can make an answer - I will accept.

Comment: All good, I'm just happy to have helped. Rep isn't that important

Comment: @Chiefir Please could you post your solution as an answer? Then you can accept it, which marks the question as solved.

Comment: @Josh I know about that, but that is not actually the direct answer to the question - that is another way of getting what I wanted to get.